# Module not found: Can't resolve react-raphael-map

Tags: node.js, reactjs, create-react-app

Im trying to use react-raphael-map over creat-react-app but apear the the problem

`./src/App.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-raphael-map' in 'C:\workspace\maptestproject\src'`

I ran `create-react-app maptestproject`;

Then `npm install --save raphael`

Then `npm install --save react-raphael-map`

And the App.js was modified to:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Map from 'react-raphael-map';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    var china= {
        aomen: {
            name: "澳门",
            path: "M413.032...",
            yy: 10
        },
        hk:{
            name: "香港",
            path: "M417.745...",
            xx: 20
        },
        taiwan: {
            name: "台湾",
            path: "M505.438..."
        },
        guangdong: {
            name: "广东",
            path: "M391.37...",
            yy: -10
        },
        guangxi: {
            name: "广西",
            path: "M305.646..."
        }
    }

    return (<Map data={china} width={480} height={560} />)
  }
}

export default App;
```

In his example the react-raphael-map has babel and webpack files in his structure, by the way create-react-app doesnt. Is it necessary?

Someone how to solve?

Comment: did you `npm install react-raphael-map`? I think you should provide more details to your question.

Comment: yeah `npm install --save react-raphael-map`

Comment: Did you run the npm install command in ./src? If so, in ./node_modules/ there should be react-raphael-map. Can you verify that?

Comment: yeah react-raphael-map folder inside node_modules

Comment: @ulima69 as I mentioned earlier, we might need more information on your issue. How about showing us a code snippet?

Answer (score -1):

The problem was in `node_modules\react-raphael-map`, on `package.json` file the line `"main": "index.js"` line points to `index.js` but there's no. The `index.js` is inside `node_modules\react-raphael-map\lib`.